# Express and Sequelize: Set foreign key in router post

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to make it so that when a post request to `/api/routines` is called, a row in the routines table is created and sets the userId foreign key to the current user. Here is my Routine model:

```
const Routine = db.define('routine', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my associations:

```
User.hasMany(Routine)
Routine.belongsTo(User)
```

And here is my router post method:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const routine = await Routine.create({
            name: req.body.Title
        })
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: req.body.user } })
        await routine.setUser(user) //This is where I need help! This line doesn't work
        await user.hasOne(routine)
        res.json(routine)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

I am not sure how to add a foreign key linking the routine to the user. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that, I think, does what you want. First you'll need to keep the ID of who's logged in in your context. To do this, I have the following imports in my `src/index.js` file:

```
import models, { sequelize } from './models';
import routes from './routes';
```

Then, further down in that same file, I have the following code:

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    req.context = {
      models,
      me: await models.User.findByLogin(username),
    };
    next();
  });
```

Where the `username` variable holds the name of the currently logged in user.

Then, I have an `answer` end-point where users can post answers, which is similar to your `routine` end-point. The posting route looks as follows in my case:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const answer = await req.context.models.Answer.create({
    text: req.body.text,
    userId: req.context.me.id,
  });

  return res.send(answer);
});
```

As you can see, I am posting the answer text and the user ID all at once. In your case, I think it would look as follows:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const routine = await Routine.create({
            name: req.body.Title,
            userId: req.context.me.id
        });

        return res.json(routine);

    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

Note that you will have to adjust `userId` in the code above to whatever field name you are using.